# autodesk-forge translating and vieweing recap rcp Files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Is it possible to translate and view recap RCP files in forge?

I see that RCP files are on the list of [supported translations](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations/) however it is my understanding that RCP files are just the recap project files and not the actual point files.

I tried running translations on both the RCP file and a zip file of the RCP and the support folder with the RCS file however it fails on both with a "Extractor error code -1"

```
{
    "type": "manifest",
    "hasThumbnail": "false",
    "status": "failed",
    "progress": "complete",
    "region": "US",
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6emlwdGVzdGJ1Y2tldC9hc2RmLnppcA",
    "version": "1.0",
    "derivatives": [
        {
            "name": "asdf.rcp",
            "hasThumbnail": "false",
            "status": "failed",
            "progress": "complete",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "type": "error",
                    "message": "Extractor error code -1",
                    "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
                }
            ],
            "outputType": "svf",
            "children": [
                {
                    "guid": "63322a82-93e7-4d04-9c9c-844c23037ba6",
                    "type": "geometry",
                    "role": "3d",
                    "name": "scene"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I may be just misunderstanding the Recap format but does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jason Kroll, I am doing some tests and will get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi @Jason Kroll,  sorry for letting you wait. I tested with the sample files.  The problem can reproduce. *rcp only or *rcp + supported files package (zip). I have to check with the engineer team to get clarification. thank you for your patience

Comment: Thank you @XiaodongLiang for following up on this. Hopefully the engineering team can clarify the issue.

Comment: Hi @Jason Kroll, I got to know only *.rcp files generated from ReCap Photo and the photo reconstruction forge service can be translated to svf using the model derivative api. Scans and point cloud projects are currently not supported for viewing on LMV. It looks you are also testing a *.rcp from a laser scanning package (rcs). Sorry if this is a bad news to you.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the help @XiaodongLiang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Xiaodong's comment it seems point clouds from laser scans aren't supported yet, only ReCap Photo.

I was trying a laser scan project which is why it did not work.